# Printing delimitated string from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, printing, delimiter

I am trying to make a simple program that takes a text file as input and then prints out a five day temperature forecast from the file. I am having trouble with getting the correct value to print from the delimited string. Any ideas where I went wrong here? My output is attached below.

```
print("File:")
f = input()
a = open(f, 'r')
b = a.read()
c = b.split(',')
a.close()
count = 1 
for i in c:
    print("Day {}: {}".format(count, c))
    count = count + 1
```

[image]

Comment: [ask]. Pls, show the example of those files.

Comment: the file would look something like 45, 65, 70, 23, 12

Comment: @liam12808 *Paste* the contents of the file.

Comment: I don't have access to the file, it's generated every time I run the code by the online textbook I use, but that is the format of each test file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.close() should be used on the file object.

you should use a.close() to close file.

**b** is a string resulting of the "read()" executed on the **a** object (your file)

Once you have that problem solved you can continue trying if your program is working as you expected.

**Edit:**

Now that you've solved that problem, there's something else I think you should look into.

On your print statement, you ouput the **c** array, wich comes from splitting the first line of the file, and only the first one. You're not looping through the file lines. That's why you always get the same array as output for each day.

If your goal is to print one number per day, then your code should be:

```
for i in c:
    print("Day {}: {}".format(count, i))
    count = count + 1
```

If your goal is to repeat this process for every line inside the file, then you should do something like:

```
for line in f:
    #your code
```

Comment: still gives me an error even after that change. I have updated the original post with the new error

Comment: By "still gives me an error" do you mean it's not returning what you expected or throwing an exception like the first time ? Also: inside your file you have one number (temperature) by line. Where do you differentiate days ?

Comment: the day is not given in the file, the file only contains 5 temperatures separated by commas. right now it is printing out the entire line instead of the correct temperature

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope I help you someway, but I'm having real trouble understanding what you're trying to do. The way you describe the input file does not compute to what you have on your screenshot, it's getting really hard for me to help you.

Comment: your first solution was correct. I would have been more specific but the online textbook that checks my code is very confusing so I don't even know what I'm trying to do half the time